# Using the SOAP api with OAuth

Tags: soap-api, c#, oauth

I want to start using OAuth with my SOAP api bindings, however my app it a process that runs  using a single user's credentials, therefore there is no need for a callback url.

Is it possible to use OAuth with no callback url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oauth 2.0 UserName-Password flow might be the right use case for you, please check more details here : https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm